# A SELECT statement to iterate over all rows of a subquery and for each row (“r”) return a value that is the result of a further query informed by “r”

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In MySQL, is it possible in a SELECT statement to iterate over all rows of a subquery and for each row (“r”) return a value that is the result of a further query informed by “r”?

E.g. if I have a table of friend’s dates of birth, how can I get from another table of famous people’s dates of birth the most recent such famous person’s birthday that’s close to each friend’s date of birth?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5d62f

I hope to generate a matching_birth_dates table with the following rows:

| id | famous_name | friend_name | famous_dob | friend_dob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David Beckham | Sarah Holland | 05/01/1980 | 07/02/1981 |
| 2 | David Lynch | John Smith | 02/05/1960 | 02/06/1959 |
| 3 | David Beckham | Jane Doe | 05/01/1980 | 02/04/1972 |

Comment: For advice on how to improve your question see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and then edit your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a SQL Fiddle and expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can first find out the closest famous person in a subquery and then get the person and the famous in the outer query:

```
select friend.id, f.name, friend.name, f.dob, friend.dob
from (
  select fa.id, fa.name, fa.dob, min(abs(datediff(fa.dob, fr.dob))) as diff
  from famous_birth_dates fa
    join friends_birth_dates fr on 1=1
  group by fa.id, fa.name, fa.dob
) as f
  join friends_birth_dates friend on f.diff = abs(datediff(f.dob, friend.dob))
order by friend.id
```

See db [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5d62f/11)